# Time Input Field in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble trying to write a form with time field using ASP.NET MVC 4.

Model:

```
class Abcde {
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime ATime { get; set; }
}
```

View.cshtml

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ATime)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ATime)
```

The validation always failed when I tried to input a time (hh:nn:ss), and said it was not in the corrent format, so i have to input a date instead.
My Question is should I change the type to `TimeSpan`? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 9):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }`
```

Try this, you can format in the DataFormatString the way you want it to work for you, im using it in a project now and it's working for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me, getting "--:-- --" in the text box, no picker. Inspecting the source gives the expected "4:00" for the html value.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is what worked for me.

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime Hour { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

This code is correct. But it only works when you use `EditorFor` instead of `TextBoxFor`.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}")]
public DateTime FieldTime{ get; set; }
```

You need to match your date validation with the format that works internally for this annotation. So, adding the ApplyFormat passing a String Pattern you can get it.

Comment: This may be the correct answer, but please explain *why* it's the correct answer :)

Comment: @Willian write some explanation of your code what and why. Thanks