# Show Time in format hh:mm:ss

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a view containing a form in ASP.NET MVC4 for a model containing time span. Here i want to show time in HH:MM:SS

// My Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> ForecastTime { get; set; }
```

// My View

```
<td class="edittime">
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.ForecastTime)
</td>
```

By using this I get format such as 10:30 AM or PM

What can i do to show it with hh:mm:ss

Thanks in advance !

Comment: <td class="edittime">
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.ForecastTime.Value.ToString("H:mm:ss"))
</td>

Comment: I tried it. But it is throwing exception Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: before you add the `datatype.time` add `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm:ss}")]`, replace `sytem.timespan` with `datatime` and use the view like you did... this should work if 1st crashed

Comment: Tried Still not working :( It is showing AM PM when I'am using Datatype.Time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17565435/1707033 I can't try it at the moment cause I'm on mobile :(

Comment: Tried in many ways still not working :(

Comment: Sorry to tell you this but probably you will not have any luck with it; input type time is limited to few browsers; also you can add seconds using a custom parameter to this control called step which can have any numeric value except 0(you will need to do this from jQuery or javascript after the html rendered into the page); I didn't found a way to make the hour format to 24h so you have 12h with am/pm. So probably you shall skip it until html 6 will appear on the market

Comment: Ok I will try out this with jQuery. Thanks for your help @HellBaby