# Time format for DateTime on page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, time

I have a property

```
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mmtt}")]
    public DateTime DeadlineTime { get; set; }
```

use it on page

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeadlineTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeadlineTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeadlineTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

but when I try to enter the value like : 11:30PM I get a validator error:

> The field DeadlineTime must be a date.

why and how to solve it?

Comment: Why dont use `TimeSpan`?

Comment: research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284385/the-field-must-be-a-date-datepicker-validation-fails-in-chrome-mvc

Comment: @dlatikay I have problem with time, not date. So, datepicker does not link with my problem

Comment: I understand. still, the fourth answer in that article I mentioned hints at a problem which might apply in your situation: does the input control render as `<input type="date" />` on client side?

Comment: @dlatikay Of course, type will be "date" if type of model property is "DateTime". If I changed it on TimeSpan then attribute [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mmtt}")] would not work

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986425/time-input-field-in-asp-net-mvc) suggests that you need to decorate the DeadlineTime declaration with an additional attribute: `[DataType(DataType.Time)]`

Comment: `11:30PM` cannot be parsed to typeof `DateTime` (it has no year, month or day component. Your property needs to be `TimeSpan` or you need a custom `ModelBinder` to convert the value to a `DateTime`