# T-SQL has a `time` data type -- does C# have just `time`, instead of `datetime` data type?

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm learning, and still getting used to, asp.net-mvc, and C#, and the 'T' version of SQL.

I have a database where I made one field `DueDate`, data type `Date`... and another field `DueTime`, data type `Time` in the `.sql` file to create the table and seed it with some example entries.

But in my `model.cs`, in C#, it seems there is only the `DateTime` data type in C#?

But using that data type makes it so that in the View, you have to enter a date *and* a time for the `DueTime` field, which is neither what I want, nor is it convenient or palatable for users.

I have searched the documentation, and googled for examples, and I can't seem to find any example similar enough to what I'm doing, that I could extrapolate something.

Here is the `.sql` file to create & seed the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Homeworks]      /* use plural db name */
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Priority]  NVARCHAR(18)        NOT NULL,
    [DueDate]   DATE        NOT NULL,
    [DueTime]   TIME(0)     NOT NULL,
    [Dept]      NVARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    [Course]    NVARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    [Assignment]    NVARCHAR(64)    NOT NULL,
    [Notes]     NTEXT       NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Homeworks] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Homeworks] (Priority, DueDate, DueTime, Dept, Course, Assignment, Notes) VALUES
    ('super-important','2019-11-11','11:59:00', 'CS', '123', 'Questions/Answers', 'best to read ch 5 first'),
    ('meh','2019-11-18','11:59:00','CS','234','write helloWorld program','find out how to write a helloWorld program'),
    ('important','2019-11-13','11:59:00','MTH','123','chapter 3 problems','do the odd-numbered ones'),
    ('regular','2019-11-15','11:59:00','WR','101','write essay paper','figure out something to write an essay about'),
    ('notes','2019-11-14','11:59:00','CS','189','do up notes over chapters 1-5','make sure you know that crap for the mid-term')

GO
```

Here is the relevant section of the model class:

```cs
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Due Date")]
        public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

        //------------------------------------------------------------
        [DisplayName("Due Time"), Required]
        public DateTime DueTime { get; set; }
```

It all works, as in being functional when you run the page on `localhost` -- as long as you enter the full date in the `time` field.  But input goes into the database as it should.

How do I get the form to accept simply the time, in the `time` field?  What data type to I use?

Comment: @aage Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time-c-sharp) is closer -- but still, I tried following that example, and get errors all over..... I'm just not sure how to pull it all together -- there's gotta be a way!

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565435/5803406) would work? Essentially requiring the model to be submitted in a time format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .Net framework does not have a built in `Time` type nor does it have a built in `Date` type.
It does have `TimeSpan`, but that is not the same as `Time` - A c# `TimeSpan` is actually a duration - the amount of time between two points in time - while SQL Server's `Time` data type is actually the time of day - and is also [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as such:

> Defines a time of a day. The time is without time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.

It's range is `00:00:00.0000000` through `23:59:59.9999999`.

The .Net's [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) struct, however, is documented as

> Represents a time interval.

and it's range spans from it's `MinValue` through has `MaxValue` fields, which are

`-10675199.02:48:05.4775808` through `10675199.02:48:05.4775807`.

Having said all that, since the .Net framework has no `TimeOfDay` data type, it use a `TimeSpan` to map to SQL Server's `Time` data type, and you can feel free to use that data type to represent the time of day (that's also the type of the `DateTime`'s struct `Time` property, which means that the .Net framework itself use this type to represent time of day.

If you want an alternative date time api for .Net, you should check out [`NodaTime`](https://nodatime.org/).